# setParent() not showing child widget

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

I have a class called TitleBar inherited from QWidget and I created a new widget and did setparent() but after doing setparent child widget is not showing, it is showing only after commenting setparent but not alligned with parent, its displaying in some random placess, On maximized view only it shows on right place

```
TitleBar::TitleBar(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)  
{
  m_jobSubmitWidget = csJobSubmitPoolWidget::getSubmitPoolInst();
 // m_jobSubmitWidget->setParent(QWidget::window());
}

void csTitleBar::BtnClicked()
{
    QPoint pos = m_queueBtn->pos() + m_serverToolBar->pos() + QPoint(-m_jobSubmitWidget->width() + m_queueBtn->width(),62); // these are member variables in TitleBar class
    // pos shows always same value on moving parent widget

    if(itemCount > 2){
        m_jobSubmitWidget->move(pos);
        m_jobSubmitWidget->show();
        m_jobSubmitWidget->setFocus();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest that you take a good read at [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html).

QWidgets that have a parent are displayed inside their parent (except for QDialog). If a widget does not have a parent, it will be shown as a separate window.

Parenting a widget to the result of `QWidget::window()` is kind of hazardous as you don't really know which widget will be returned, so you do not know where the child widget will end up.

Also you do not need to call `show()` on widgets that have a parent. By default their visibility follows the parent visibility.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also had to add the widget which I was changing the parent (here `textEdit`) to the target containing layout:

```
ui->textEdit->setParent(ui->groupBox1);
m_lastVboxLayout->removeWidget(ui->textEdit);
m_lastVboxLayout = ui->verticalLayout_groupBox1;
m_lastVboxLayout->addWidget(ui->textEdit);
```

no need to call `show()` afterwards.